# AJV doesn't validate my body with the function returned by compile

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ajv

I'm building an API with express and I use AJV as a middleware to validate the body which is sent.

I'm using AJV **6.12.6**

This is my schema in JSON **body-foobar.json**:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foobar": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": ["foobar"]
}
```

Here the way I use the middleware:

```
const validator = require('../../middleware/validator')
const schema = require('../../middleware/schema/body-foobar.json')
...

router.post('/foo', validator(schema, 'body'), post.handler)
```

And finally my middleware:

```
const Ajv = require('ajv')


module.exports = (schema, data) => {
  const ajv = new Ajv()
  const validate = ajv.compile(schema)

  return (req, res, next) => {
    const validation = validate(schema, req[data])

    if (!validation) {
      return res.status(400).json({success: validation, error: validate.errors[0].message})
    }
    return next()
  }
}
```

With this code, AJV never validates my body and says that `foobar` is missing but there is, if I remove the required parameter it works but if I put a number instead of a string for the param `foobar` it will validate my body...

To make it works as expected, I have to not call the function returned by compile but call:

`ajv.validate(schema, req[data])`

This way, it makes the compile function useless, and I'm afraid of performances (cached, or compile for each request).
Did I make a mistake by using the function returned by compile? How can I make it works this way? Because it's super weird that it works well one way but not the other ...

Thank you for your help

Comment: thanks, this seemingly uninteresting post actually helped me in ways you cant imagine! now I understand you can have multiple (req, res, next) handlers in Express :)

Comment: so impressed with this approach - I'm using this approach in conjunction with TS and ts-json-schema-generator and its enabling me to validate my roots so well and so fast - many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returned by compile has different parameters than `ajv.validate` and no need de specify the schema.

I just need to call: `validate(req[data]` and it's working fine.